# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'windows' "how to solve this problem?"

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-python

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'windows'
File "C:\Users\82105.vscode\Student-Management-System-in-Python-main\Student-Management-System-in-Python-main\windows\login_win.py", line 3, in 
from windows import backend as bk, superadmin as sp, admin as ad, faculty, student
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'windows'

I wrote codes as below codes

from tkinter import *
from tktooltip import ToolTip
from windows import backend as bk, superadmin as sp, admin as ad, faculty, student
from tkinter import messagebox as mb, simpledialog as sd
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

pip install windows

install windows

I installed Windows from cmd, but it says there is no module.